# Git pull origin <branch> overwrites master?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, remote-branch

I have a repository on Github, **aav1**

On my laptop I have two branches, one called **master** and one called **vs12up**
The master branch was when the software was Visual Studio 2008, vs12up is converted to Visual Studio 2012.

On my laptop everything seems fine and I pushed the new branch to github, appears correct.

On my desktop I tried to pull the remote branch:

```
git pull origin vs12up
```

It wrote the changes to my master branch on the desktop, **git log** shows the commits made on the **vs12up** branch, but git branch only shows **master**, which is the current branch.

How can I revert the changes to the **master** branch and pull the **vs12up** branch on my desktop to match the repository on my laptop?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you do a `git pull` with a remote branch name, it will fetch the remote branch and then merge it into your current local branch. So to undo that, you will first have to reset your local branch to the remote `master`, then create a new local `vs12up` branch from the corresponding remote branch.

1. Reset your local `master` to match the remote repository's `master` (WARNING: be sure that you don't have any uncommitted changes you want to keep before issuing the following command):

   ```
   git reset --hard origin/master
   ```
2. Fetch all remote branches into your local repository:

   ```
   git fetch origin
   ```
3. Create a new local `vsup12` branch from the remote `vsup12` branch, and switch to this new local branch:

   ```
   git checkout -b vsup12 origin/vsup12
   ```

Note that when you subsequently just do a `git pull` while switched to the `vsup12` branch, you'll fetch and merge the latest changes from the `vsup12` branch on Github into your local `vsup12`

Comment: Thank you. Two questions, what does the -b argument do?

Comment: And do I just switch back by git checkout master?

Comment: The `-b` specifies the name of the new branch. `git checkout -b foo` is shorthand for creating a branch called `foo` (with `git branch foo`) and then switching to it (with `git checkout foo`).

Comment: On the desktop, after I followed instructions above git status returns # Your branch is ahead of 'aav1/vs12up' by 1 commit.  - but it says everything is up to date, nothing to commit. Is this normal?

Comment: Assuming that your remote is really called `aav1` and not `origin`, that would indicate that you have a new commit locally which is not yet in your remote repository. When doing the above, that'd not be normal. Maybe you did an inadvertent pull/merge in between? But I fear that's either a separate question or something for [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Sorry - the remote is called origin on my laptop, aav1 on my desktop. I messed up on my naming, my mistake. I didn't do a merge, just the pull that I asked the question above. Everything seems up to date however. I'm going to make a small commit and compare the differences. Thank you for your help again.